# Hololens worldanchorstore reset / persistence

Tags: c#, hololens

It appears to me that the WorldAnchorStore gets reset when I deploy a new version of my application.

First, is that correct or how does this work?

Second, what is a strategy for persisting my WorldAnchorStore from version to version or even device to device?

Comment: Is this the case anytime you deploy a new compiled version, or is it only when you change the version number?

Comment: it's been a while since I have developed on HoloLens now, but if memory serves me correctly it was for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official strategy for persisting the WorldAnchorStore from Version to Version.

To share between devices you can use the sharing service and have each of your clients connect to it, this is done in HoloAcademy lesson [Holograms 240](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_240).  This suffers from a similar problem though, once the "server side" shuts down there is no persistence so all anchors are lost.

Because of this I found this solution to be a little half baked at the moment and my strategy is to implement a web service in Azure that my clients connect to in order to store all of the anchors between sessions/installs as well as share them.